# Wordpress post into Jquery mobile framework

Tags: wordpress, jquery, mobile, frameworks

I want to show my wordpress post into jquery mobile application... But so far i didnt got the success. I am using `jquery.post()` function but my response comes empty....

Request to the desired url goes well , status comes 200 ok but response coming is always blank :(  Although the same post function & url is working fine in other php pages....

below is my code

```
function get_Time(cityCode,date){
  jQuery.post(
    "http://test.local/time/", 
    { city: cityCode, date:date}, 
    function (data){jQuery('#print_time').html(data);}
    );

 }

function _get_Time(response)
{
    alert("response:"+response);
    var time = new Array();
    time = response.split('|')
    jQuery("#print_time").html(time[0]);
}
```

Please give me some solution for showing my wordpress post (only text + links) content into my jquery mobile applicaton....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about what you are going to do. It seems to me, like you want to retrieve a certain WordPress post content + additional information via Ajax, I think the easiest way to do it is the following:

1. Write a custom server-side PHP-Script (which possibly takes a WordPress Slug or ID)
2. Create a connection to the database in this script, get the post contents you want to have and return these as text or JSON to your JQuery mobile and use it

It might work in a way like this (not tested):

```
include ‘path-to-wp-directory/wp-blog-header.php’;

$post_id=0;

if(isset($_REQUEST['post_id'])) {
$post_id=intval($_REQUEST['post_id']);
}

global $wpdb;

$post_content = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_content FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_id=".$post_id." AND post_status='publish'";

echo $post_content;
```

This is only possible if you have access to the server, of course. If you want to get Post Content from an external WordPress Blog, then you should consider using the RSS Feed.

The following article shows how to  load WordPress functions in an external PHP Script, which also might be useful: http://www.bloggingtips.com/2009/01/25/use-wordpress-functions-externally/